# Not able to install demo applications of Red5 on CentOS

Tags: curl, proxy, centos, red5, kaltura

I have installed the Kaltura Single Server Setup on a CentOS machine.

I am facing issue with Red5 server, I am not able to install the oflaDemo application or anyother application.

When visit `http://myhost.com:5080/` and when I select `Installater` page, then in logs I get error as:

```
org.red5.server.service.Installer - Unable to connect to http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/
```

The list of the application is empty.

On some posts it is suggested to download war files manually and copy it in the `webapps` folder so that red5 will install the war files.

Is this the only solution for this problem?

When I host this url usinf 'curl' command then also it works and it returns the html page with app list.

To fix this issue, tied to set the proxy information in the red5.sh file under JAVA_OPTS and ANT_OPTS as below:

```
JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=port -Dhttp.proxyUserName=myuser -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypass"  
ANT_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=host -Dhttp.proxyPort=port -Dhttp.proxyUserName=myuser -Dhttp.proxyPassword=mypass"
```

Also exported these as the env variables, still getting the same error.

Somehow I want to get oflaDemo working.

**--- UPDATE ---**

As mentioned I have installed oflaDemo application by copying the war file in `webapps` directory, when i visit the page `http://myhost.com:5080/oflaDemo` then I get two video windows (RTMP & RTMPT) with play button nothing else in the page, and when I select play button then it starts to load and then after it displays error `[Server.Reject]:(_defaultRoot_._defaultVHost_):Application (oflaDemo) is not defined.` and for RTMPT video I get error `Server not found: rtmpt://localhost:5080/oflaDemo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Unable to connect" means you won't get the application list. The downloading of the apps outside the installer app is an option when the installer is not working for whatever reason, here are the direct links:
[oflaDemo](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/oflaDemo-java6.war)

[admin](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/admin-r4506-java6.war)

[SOSample](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/SOSample-r4326-java6.war)

Grab any or all of those wars and put them in your red5/webapps directory; they will be installed by the war service, or you can just restart your server and avoid the wait.

Lastly, I think your OPTS entries are incorrect as you are not specifying actual hosts nor ports; you also don't need the proxy options unless your connection requires it.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, please see my updated question, I did try to copy war file for `oflaDemo` and try to play demo from the browser, and For OPTS entries I removed the actual host/port/user/pass just to post it here, but I am providing actual/proper values for these parameters in my `red5.sh` file.

Comment: After replacing `localhost` with the host name my Red5 host in file `index.hml` of `oflaDemo`, I am able to see the stream. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Now I am able to see the oflademo in the url how to start stream?

Comment: Using the demo app, connect and select a vod file